# Java 8 Stream Api Filter specific range

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list like this:

```
int[] counting = new int[]{1,0,-1,-2,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2,1,0,-1,0,1,2};
```

I want to filter if there is a negative value between 0 and 0 numbers.

For above list, result should return 2 because between 0 and 0 there is a negative number and it also valid for third range.

```
List<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(counting).filter(x ->  ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can i collect range values? After that how can I check there is a negative number or not?

In other words I want to count how many pairs of (0, 0) there are with a negative value between them. So since there’s a negative value in -1,-2,-1,-2,-1 and one in -1, the count of such pairs is 2.

Comment: Is your question, *Count possible ranges between two 0s? If there is a negative number between the 0s, don't count it.*?

Comment: Do you want to count how many pairs of (0, 0) there are with a negative value between them? So since there’s a negative value in -1,-2,-1,-2,-1 and one in -1, the count of such pairs is 2?

Comment: @OleV.V..Yes.What I want to do is exactly this.

Comment: Would (0, -1, 0, -1, 0) be a possible input, and would the count be 2 too in this case? What I am asking is whether the same 0 can be part of two pairs of (0, 0). Also, would (-1, 0, 1, 0, -1) be possible and result in a count of 0 since the negative values are not between 0 and 0? Please clarify *in the question* ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55275628/edit) it) so we have all information in one place, thank you.

Comment: starting point is always 0.So, (-1, 0, 1, 0, -1) is not valid.

Comment: Would (0, -1, 0, -1, 0) be a possible input, and would the count be 2 too in this case? Yes.Answer is 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t use a stream pipeline for that. Streams are well suited for independent processing and filtering of elements. They are not suited for processing that depends on the presence or absence of other elements in the stream (here 0 earlier and later).

Use a loop. Before entering the loop, check that the first element in the list is 0 as required, and throw an exception if not (so your example list from the question won’t pass this test). Declare some variables that we need during looping:

```
   int negativeCount = 0;
   boolean hasSeenNegativeSinceLastZero = false;
```

In your loop, each time you see a negative number, set `hasSeenNegativeSinceLastZero` to true. Each time you see a 0, if `hasSeenNegativeSinceLastZero` is true, then add 1 to the count and set `hasSeenNegativeSinceLastZero` to false.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stream-based solution. I doubt it's more readable than a simple for loop.

```
int[] zeroIndices = IntStream.range(0, counting.length)
                .filter(i -> 0 == counting[i])
                .toArray();

long count = IntStream.range(0, zeroIndices.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> new int[] { i, zeroIndices[i] })
        .skip(1)
        .filter(arr -> Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(counting, 
                                                        zeroIndices[arr[0] - 1], 
                                                        arr[1]))
                             .anyMatch(i -> i < 0))
        .count();
```

Comment: It *can* be done. I hadn’t seen that coming. Thanks for the demonstration. I share your doubt, though…

Comment: [My version is here](https://ideone.com/rN7MJl). It may be slightly simpler (and may still not be as simple as the loop solution). Thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @OleV.V., your suggestion helped me use the simpler combination of filter and range.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think stream solution will be readable, you should use a simple looping, but you can mix a bit. Here what I think it should be like

```
int[] counting = new int[] {1, 0, -1, -2, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2};

List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
for (var i = 0; i < counting.length; i++) {
  if (counting[i] == 0) {
    indices.add(i);
  }
}

if (indices.size() % 2 == 0) {
  System.out.println("You got " + indices.size() / 2 + " pairs");
} else {
  System.err.println(
      "You don't have complete pairs, you have only " + indices.size() / 2 + " pairs");
  System.exit(-1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < indices.size(); i = i + 2) {
  System.out.println("-----Pair----");
  stream(copyOfRange(counting, indices.get(i), indices.get(i + 1)))
      .filter(v -> v < 0)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

It will print each pair output like this

```
You got 2 pairs
-----Pair----
-1
-2
-1
-2
-1
-----Pair----
-1
```